# How to add an image in a table (using el-table, el-table-column), ie using ui-element in Vue.js?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, element-ui

I am fairly new to Vue.js and have managed to build a simple table using the ui-element. The ui-element used for building the table is el-table and have displayed the various columns using el-table-column and prop (please find the code below). Now, I want to display images/avatars/thumbnail images in my table (ie, one of the column in the table should be filled with images). I do not know how to insert images in the tables as I am using **prop** to populate the table with data. My table code is as follows:

The HTML part in Vuejs:

```
<!--Table-->
    
          <el-table :data="posts"
                ref="Table"
                stripe
                style="width: 100%;">

                <el-table-column min-width="50" prop="name"
                   label="Username">
                </el-table-column>

                <el-table-column min-width="50" prop="count_followers"
                   label="Followers">
                </el-table-column>

                <el-table-column min-width="55"  prop="display_pic_url"
                   label="Display Pic">
                </el-table-column> -->
           </el-table>
```

I have consumed the data using axios and stored the information in an array called **posts** . I have used the posts array above in the html code, that is, :data = "posts". I have displayed the data on the web page using el-table-column and prop. The third column above represents the display picture, prop = "display_pic_url" represents the profile picture urls. But, I do not want to print this data (ie, the urls of the display pictire) on the table, instead, I want to display the profile picture hosted on the url. How do I achieve this? How do I display the profile picture in each row instead of just printing the url in each row?

I have displayed the table I have created below.

[image]

Please take a look at the code and suggest the modifications in the code to display the profile picture.

I would really appreciate any help I could get.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using slot-scope:

```
<el-table-column min-width="55"  prop="display_pic_url" label="Display Pic">
  <template slot-scope="scope">
      <img :src="scope.row.display_pic_url"/>
  </template>
</el-table-column>
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the color of the text for a specific column only for each row using el-table-column? el-table-column does not seem to have color attribute and I cannot think of a way to style it. Would appreciate your help. Example, if I want to make the contents of the column Followers as Blue, then how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can using slot-scope like this:

```
<el-table-column align="center" label="Photo">
  <template slot-scope="scope">                        
     <img :src="`/uploads/${scope.row.image}`"  width="50px"/>                         
  </template>
</el-table-column>
```